# Creating class instance with const in constructor

Tags: c++, int, constants

I have struct:

```
struct Ammo
{
public:
    const int MAX_MAGAZINES;
    const int MAX_IN_MAGAZINE;
    int currMagazineAmmo;
    int totalAmmo;
    Ammo(int maxMag, int maxMagAmmo) : MAX_MAGAZINES(maxMag), MAX_IN_MAGAZINE(maxMagAmmo)
    {
        currMagazineAmmo = totalAmmo = 0;
    }
    ~Ammo()
    {

    }
    bool MagazineNotEmpty() {return currMagazineAmmo > 0;}
    bool NotEmpty() {return totalAmmo > 0;}
};
```

and in my cpp I dont know how to make new Ammo variable and initialize these consts,
I tried this:

```
Ammo gun(10,40);
```

and this

```
Ammo gun = new Ammo(10,40);
```

but none of them works. Thanks

EDIT:

I have also class CPlayer where i create the Ammo object:

```
    class CPlayer
    {
    public:
    //...
    Ammo gun{10,40};//there is error
    Ammo bow(10,40);//also error 'expected a type specifier'

    CPlayer() {...}
    ~CPlayer() {...}
    }
```

but I can't compile it.

EDIT2 ---------------------------------------------------
I've rewritten the problem into console:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Ammo
{
    const int MAX;
    const int MAX2;

    Ammo(int a, int b) : MAX(a), MAX2(b)
    {

    }
    ~Ammo() {}
};

class CA
{
public:
    int health;
            Ammo amm(10,10);//error 'expected a type specifier'
    Ammo amm2{10,10};//error 'expected a ;'

    CA(){}
    ~CA(){}
};

int main()
{
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is how to add Ammo object to a class?

Comment: new creates pointer, Ammo* is not convertible into Ammo, so last example will never be valid. The other one is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse problem

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, `Ammo gun(10,40);` should definitely work. The second one should definitely fail because C++ is not Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it now! I had to set constructor of the Ammo structure in constructor of CA class.

```
class CA
{
public:
    int health;
    Ammo amm;

    CA() : amm(10,100)
    {

        std::cout << "Yeah!" << amm.MAX << " " << amm.MAX2;
    }
    ~CA(){}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first example initialize const variables. Crosscheck: http://ideone.com/M55Mls

```
Ammo gun{10,40};
std::cout << gun.MAX_MAGAZINES;
```

Second should not compile. You cant assign Ammo to Ammo*. Check what `operator new` returns. Please get familiar with smart pointer. Manual memory allocation is not recommended in c++ anymore.

There is no problem with most vexing parse right not. To avoid problems with most vexing parse in the future please use uniform brace initialization from c++11:     `Ammo gun{10,40};`

Comment: Yes. No one told there is one. Edited for better understanding.